# I'm recreating snake in Python, I've set the base up but i'm at a road block for how to refresh/update the screen

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
root =  Tk()
root.geometry('400x400')
root.title('Snake')
#root['background'] = ''
canvas = Canvas(root,width = 400,height = 400,bg = '#FF0000')
canvas.pack()
```

> > ### Heading ###class used to setup snake with methods.

```
class Snake:
    def __init__(self):
        self.width = 10
        self.height = 10
        self.snake_length = [1]
    def draw_cell(self,pos_x,pos_y):
        # pos_x, pos_y will be divided by 20 so we times by 20
        canvas.create_rectangle(pos_x*20,pos_y*20,pos_x*20+20,pos_y*20+20)
    def draw_snake(self):
        for i in range(0,len(self.snake_length)):
            self.draw_cell(10,10)
    def movement(self):
        




def grid():
    for i in range(0,20):
        for j in range(0,20):
            canvas.create_rectangle(i*20,j*20,i*20+20,j*20+20,fill = '#ff6347'
```

> > ##starting up everything also checking things

```
grid()
a = Snake()
a.draw_snake()
root.mainloop()
```

> Im not very good at python, so any extra help with silly mistakes would be helpful :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function/method you are looking for would redraw the grid and then draw your snake.
Since you already created the functions/methods to do this, the actual implementation of this should be easy as that:

```
def update():
    grid()
    a.draw_snake()
```

If you want to control the refresh rate (which I would recommend since otherwise, your frame will update as often as your update function can be called) you can use the `after()` method from the `tkinter` module. You place it just before your `mainloop` call. In this example, the variable `fps` would represent the desired frames per second.

```
root.after(1000/fps, update)
```

If you are further interested in the after `method()`, you will find a pretty good explanation [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-after-method-in-tkinter/).

Comment: Thank you so much, will implement :)

Comment: don't forget to upvote the answer and mark it as correct if it works :)